# How to add libart.a for iOS platform without Xcode IDE

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, lib

I am an Android developer. Now I encountered a problem. 
I need to link art library for iOS platform. But I am not familiar with iOS and do not have Xcode IDE.
How can I link art library without Xcode IDE?
Can anyone help?

Thanks.